# Convert Date from ISO 8601 Zulu string to java.time.Instant in Java 8

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-format, java.time.instant

I want to convert string date format into java.time.Instant

I am getting exception while parsing date.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Too many pattern letters: s
```

I am using below code for conversion first from String to date.

```
    String string = "2018-07-17T09:59:51.312Z";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.sssZ", Locale.FRANCE);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(string, formatter);
    System.out.println(date);
```

I want to convert "timestamp": `"2018-07-17T09:59:51.312Z"` in format time in the ISO 8601 format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ` in the UTC timezone.

Checked [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion), but not working.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## tl;dr

> convert string date format into java.time.Instant

Skip the formatting pattern. Just parse.

```
Instant.parse( "2018-07-17T09:59:51.312Z" )
```

## ISO 8601

Yes, you used incorrect formatting pattern as indicated in the [first Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51910670/642706).

But you **needn't specify a formatting pattern** at all. Your input string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

The `Z` on the end means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), and is pronounced “Zulu”.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-07-17T09:59:51.312Z" ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

### Don’t build your own formatter

Don’t struggle with writing your own format pattern string. Your string is in an ISO 8601 format that is built into java.time. To parse into a `java.time.Instant` (as your title says):

```
    String string = "2018-07-17T09:59:51.312Z";
    Instant inst = Instant.parse(string);
    System.out.println(inst);
```

Output:

> 2018-07-17T09:59:51.312Z

To parse into a `LocalDate` (as your code snippet seems to intend):

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(string, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    System.out.println(date);
```

> 2018-07-17

### What went wrong in your code?

Format pattern letters are case sensitive (you can also see this from the tables in the first answer to the question you are linking to).

- You used uppercase `YYYY` for year. Uppercase `Y` is for week year, only useful with a week number. Use either `uuuu` or lowercase `yyyy` for year.
- Uppercase `DD` is for day of year. For day of month you need lowercase `dd`.
- Lowercase `hh` is for hour with AM or PM from 01 through 12 and only useful with an AM/PM marker. You need uppercase `HH` for hour of day from 00 through 23.
- Finally you correctly used lowercase `ss` for seconds, but also `sss` for fraction of second. For the latter you need uppercase `SSS`. This error is the reason for your error message: Since seconds only go up to 60 (including a leap second), three `s` as in `sss` does not make sense, and `DateTimeFormatter` objects to this. From the documentation:

  > Up to two letters of 'd', 'H', 'h', 'K', 'k', 'm', and 's' can be specified.

Link: [`DateTimeFormatter` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)